# Background in .css stretches

Tags: css

My background image is supposed to stay in it's fixed dimensions and it does, when I'm working in dreamweaver or opening it from my desktop via various browsers (mozilla, ie, chrome). But once it's uploaded the background image stretches. Does someone know a solution for this issue?

[Website](http://www.malamute-dog-supplies.de)

Comment: Perhaps you could show your gratitude for the help offered by marking one the responses, as the answer you were looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting this in your CSS...

```
body {
  background:url(YOUR_IMAGE);
  background-size:80px 60px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Where the size in pixels is the same as the original image dimensions.

Comment: it actual looks like that... body { 
 font-family: Arial;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font-size:12px;
 width:100%;
 background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top #FFFFFF; text-align:left;
 -moz-background-size:1152px 770px;
 -webkit-background-size:1152px 770px;
  background-size:1152px 770px;

Comment: Clear your cache fully and reload. I just tried it out on my computer and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  background:url(YOUR_IMAGE);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

This could just simply be a caching issue. If you've uploaded everything. Reload the page. When its fully loaded press ctrl + r &/or ctrl + F5. I tend to hit both alternatingly several times. This should clear the image and css from your cache.

If this doesn't work then their is something weird going on.

Its also worth noting that things like Dreamweaver will load the content as if it were a browser. Therefore something can look great in Dreamweaver but not respond as expected in a browser. Likewise (with Visual Studio) things can often look terribly broken in your software but great in a browser.

Comment: I reloaded the page already a couple of times and refreshed the uploaded index at least 10 times. That's all really weird and driving me insane. :-(

Comment: Well clearly the page is still calling the old css. That can only be due to the fact that you havent uploaded the css to the correct location, youve renamed it and not changed the reference on the web page, or you've not saved the css file updates before uploading. It can only be one of those 3 option.

Comment: You all are just great! Yes, I simply forgot to upload the style.css. Thank you very much! To all of you!

Comment: Urm should be the first thing you try really. I hope we are going to get upvotes and accepted answers for our efforts. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider developing with FireFox and installing the Firebug add-on. This is an invaluable tool that lets you check &/or edit css etc on the fly.

Using that on your site show you have your background image set to 100% & 770px. These two rules clash with each other. The first is saying make the image 100% of the screen width whilst the other is saying make the background just 770px.

You need to consider your options better here.

Comment: That's weird I actually changed it (see above)

Comment: Well thats not what is on your site then. For whatever reason its using the old style. Did you save before uploading? Did you upload to the correct directory?

Comment: Strange, yes I did I also attached some new pictures in the gallery and these are placed as they supposed to be.

Comment: Remove the Width:100% from the body style. Body is always 100% anyway. This is probably clashing with your browser specific rules:  width:100%;
 background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top #FFFFFF; text-align:left;
 -moz-background-size: 100% 770px;
 -webkit-background-size: 100% 770px;
  background-size: 100% 770px;